# Firebase onCancelled being called

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to get a very basic value from my simple `Realtime Database`

My database structure looks like this

```
project-url thing
{
     OnlineUsers: 0
```

And I am trying to get that OnlineUsers value whenever the phone opens the app.

The problem is `onCancelled` gets called instead of my `onDataChange` so it never retrieves the value. I am not sure why `onCancelled` is being called.

This is my code

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference laRef = database.getReference("OnlineUsers");
double onlineUsers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    final TickerView lotteryTicker = findViewById(R.id.tickerView);

    Log.i("HomePage", "!!Before callback");
    updatePlayers(new PlayersCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(double amount) {
            String onlineUsers = Double.toString(amount);
            Log.i("HomePage", "!!Got in");
            lotteryTicker.setText(onlineUsers);
        }
    });
    Log.i("HomePage", "!!After callback");
 }

public interface PlayersCallback {
    void onCallback(double amount);
}

public void updatePlayers(final PlayersCallback callBack) {
    Log.i("HomePage", "!!Before value listener");
    laRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            onlineUsers = (double) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.i("HomePage", "!!Inside callback");

            callBack.onCallback(onlineUsers);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("HomePage", "!!onCancelled");
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have setup a `callback` to retrieve the value and have also put some Log statements in so that I can see where the code runs. The code ultimately ends up in the `onCancelled` method so nothing really happens.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Log the DatabaseError object it gives you.  What does it say?

Comment: @DougStevenson `permissionDenied`. Does this have to do with the rules of my database?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable guess.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'll look into the rules then. Thanks. I am not sure why I didn't think about logging the error. I feel dumb. Thanks though lol

Comment: @DougStevenson I have a similar problem. Permission denied. But my security rules are very less (auth.uid !== null). Moreover, I have made sure that the user can access this activity only if he/she is successfully signed in in the previous activity. Can you kindly tell what can be the possible cause for this?